# Installing virtualbox-6.0 on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: apt, package-management, virtualbox

Ubuntu version

```
(base) vipulpopat@vipulpopat-XPS-13-9370:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan


(base) vipulpopat@vipulpopat-XPS-13-9370:~$ sudo apt install virtualbox-6.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 virtualbox-6.0 : Depends: libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libvpx3 (>= 1.5.0) but it is not installable
                  Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can someone please help me out with this ?

Regards
Vipul

Comment: It has already been asked before. https://askubuntu.com/a/1183139 
Use this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Virtualbox on Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183135/virtualbox-on-ubuntu-19-10)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)