# Can't Install virtualbox on 19.10

Tags: virtualbox

I want on install virtualbox-6.1_6.1.4 on Ubuntu 19.10. But It can't and show me `Dependency is not satisfiable: libvpx5 (>= 1.6.0)`. How can I solve it? I had try to find libvpx5 on Google, but I did't find it.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.01?   There was no Ubuntu release in 2019-January (19.01).   Please clarify (Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format).   That library is not available for eoan/19.10 though (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libvpx5)

Comment: Thank you for correction. I mean Ubuntu 19.10. I'm sorry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtualbox on Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183135/virtualbox-on-ubuntu-19-10)

Comment: Does it NEED to be the wrong-release or non-Ubuntu version of vbox? Or can you use 19.10's vbox 6.0.14? The latter works quite well and installs very easily.

Comment: I just installed it without problems. I have libvpx6 installed. Try to install libvpx6 first by running `sudo apt install libvpx6`.